# Is the title of ‘Invitation to a Murder’ a Christie reference?

Tags: reference, title, agatha-christie

[*Invitation to a Murder*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11773810/) (2023) is a made-for-television film which is loosely based on Agatha Christie’s novel [*And Then There Were None*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_Then_There_Were_None).

There are several nods to Christie’s authorship dotted throughout the film, including direct references to Hercule Poirot and the main character buying the latest Christie novel at a book shop at the start of the film.

What I am wondering is whether the title *Invitation to a Murder* is another such nod. The reason I think this may be the case is that in certain countries, one of Agatha Christie’s Miss Marple novels, *A Murder Is Announced*, was published under a title that directly translates to ‘invitation to (a) murder’; for example [*Invitation til mord* in Danish](https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invitation_til_mord) and *Invitasjon til mord* in Norwegian.

My attempts at Googling has brought up no relevant information or hints as to whether it actually is a reference.

Has anyone from the film’s production commented on this? Is it known if the title is a deliberate nod to Christie, or if it’s just coincidence?

Answer (score 2):

The next movie in that **Miranda Green Series** is ["Murder at the Embassy"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt22772712/) which ties in with Agatha Christie tropes : Egypt , Cairo , Nile , Etc.
That title is Parallel to ["The Murder at the Vicarage"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Murder_at_the_Vicarage)
It is almost certain that "Invitation to a Murder" is indeed a nod to Agatha Christie , referencing what OP has got or some other related title.

[[ It is highly likely that the titles are going to involve more of Agatha Christie tropes , though it is too early to conclude on that : the number of titles is not yet enough to claim that. ]]